# Why is the same date echoing despite being created and stored properly in db?

Tags: date, activerecord, time

I am pulling comments from my database. The `'created_on'` field I have created is inserting properly, however when I echo the results, it's a random date and time that is the same no matter what(Mar 11, 2013 at 10:50 AM).

Here is my query to pull the records:

```
public function get_airwave_comments($profile_id) 

          {

            $session = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
            $user_id= $this->session->userdata('id');
    if($profile_id == $user_id)
            {
               $comments_query = "SELECT * FROM airwaves_comments aw,users u WHERE u.id=aw.from_id AND AW.FROM_id=aw.to_id AND aw.from_id=".$profile_id." order by aw.created_on desc" ;
        }

        else
        {
            $comments_query = "SELECT * FROM airwaves_comments aw,users u WHERE u.id=aw.from_id AND aw.to_id=".$profile_id." order by aw.created_on desc" ;
        }


            $query = $this->db->query($comments_query);
                if($query->num_rows() >= 1)
                {
                   $data = $query->result_array();
                   // return whole resultset. It contains zero, one or more records
                   return $data;


                }
                else return false;

            $query = $this->db->query($poster_info_query);
                 if($query->num_rows() >= 1)
                    {
                       $data = $query->result_array();
                       // return whole resultset. It contains zero, one or more records
                       return $data;


                    }
                    else return false;

        }


}
```

Here is the view in which I'm trying to echo the `'created_on'` field properly:

```
if ($airwave && $profile_id == $session_id)
            {
                foreach ($airwave as $airwave_comment_row)
                $airwave_comment_row = $airwave[0];

                {
                    echo "<div id='profile_airwave'>";
                    echo $airwave_comment_row['comment'];
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo "<span class='profile_airwave_info'>"; 
                    echo date('M d, Y',strtotime($airwave_comment_row['created_on'])); ?> at <?php echo date('g:i A',strtotime($airwave_comment_row['created_on']));
                    echo "</span>";
                    echo "</div>";

                }
            }
```

so basically even if I just do `echo $airwave_comment_row['created_on'];` It's echoing the same said date.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I've determined that the said date is the 'created_on' row from the USERS table, not the comments table, which has a created on row as well. I've spliced together tables in the query so I could get info about the comment author.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of the datetime column in the comments table so that it was different from the datetime column in the users table it's being spliced with.